# 403 Forbidden error with fcgid and PHP

Tags: php-fpm, apache-2.4, http-status-code-403, spdy

I'm trying to configure php and mod_spdy on Apache 2.4, Debian jessie, x64. I've followed [this guide](https://plainsightro.wordpress.com/2014/09/28/mod_spdy-with-ubuntu-14-04-x64-and-apache-2-4/) and configured Apache following [this other guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php) and installed these packages:

```
libapache2-mod-fcgid
php-cgi
php5-fpm
```

I now have problems with php applications: when I try to open them I get a 403 Forbidden. Here is my /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/fcgid.conf

```
<Location />
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  Options +ExecCGI
  FcgidWrapper /usr/bin/php-cgi .php
</Location>
```

And the error I get in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
```

I've tried adding

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to the  in the PHP application VirtualHost, but the result is just the same. Why am I getting the 403?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 403 error message is misleading, but correct. Looking at /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf I have:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>
```

Following the code flow, the "Require all granted" on /usr/lib/cgi-bin gets executed only if mod_cgi and/or mod_cgid are enabled. In my case they were both disabled (because they are disabled by default in Debian).

```
# a2enmod cgi ; a2enmod cgid ; service apache2 restart
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 is often because of a missing ScriptAlias line.
eg, if the Location is "/"  and  root for the server is /var/my-www/,
put it immediately before the  directive:

```
ScriptAlias  /  /var/my-www/
<Location />
 ...
 ...
```